# How can I grab just the text within a div, if it also includes some user entry via select and input boxes?

Tags: jquery, html, text

I'm making a little madlib game for my kids, but I'm having some trouble getting the text within the div, because of the `select` and `input` elements.

for example:

```
<div class='para1'>
This is a madlib game. 
Do you <select id='no1'>
<option selected>like</option>
<option> not like </option>
</select>
this kind of game? What would you rate it as, <input type="text">.
</div>
```

using $('.para1').text() gets me all the garbage in the select boxes; using $('para1').html() gets me the markup garbage.

I want the text of the selected option and any user input - along with thenew static text in the div - can this be done?

The final output should read:
This is a madlib game. Do you like this kind of game? What would you rate it as, [input value here].

See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/4Fysw/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4Fysw/7/

As found on the jquery site about .text() it won't work on inputs or script tags, so in order to get what you are looking for I believe the only way is to make sure the format of the text supports an easy way of grabbing it, as I have done in the fiddle.

I basically wrap all the strings in `<span>` tags as they don't cause any forced styling by browser or css (of course unless you have default styling for span's), and they allow you to itterate over the children of the parent `para1` element and determine if you should use the .val() function or just the normal .text() function to get the data to build up your string.

Hope this helps.

**Update:**
Based on comment - here is a slightly refactored fiddle that supports a little more flexibility: http://jsfiddle.net/8QaFn/3/

Comment: Thank you very much! That was exactly what I was looking for. But, as a jQuery novice, can you explain the syntax here: '$('.para1').children().each(function (idx, elm) { var $elm = $(elm); ...' - So you are iterating over each child within `.para1`, which is why you interrupt the `select` or `input` elements by text within the `span`? What if I include some hidden divs which are dynamically visible within my `.para1` div. This would include those as well, correct? How can I avoid any divs with the `style="display:none" attribute?

Comment: yes basically the `$('.para1').children().each(function (idx, elm) { var $elm = $(elm); ...` portion iterates over all children within the para1 class element, so if more than 1 element had para1 class this would iterate over their children as well.

take a look at this jquery api page: http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/ this will provide you with the ability to select all children that are visible. so `$('.para1').children(':visible')...` will only select the visible elements as defined by the jquery select `:visible`. Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, that is very helpful. I appreciate the explanation. One more thing, why do you include the variable `idx` within the `.each` function? I don't see it doing anything.

Comment: it is how the jquery .each function works: https://api.jquery.com/each/
All the parameters are optional, and you can just use the `this` keyword which will mean the current element being iterated over.  I try to avoid using `this` because depending on context it can get confusing if using inside a function that already uses the `this` keyword

Answer (score 0):

Add the value attribute inside your option tags.

```
<option value="like">like</option>
```

And print it as:

```
$('#no1').val();
```

The textbox should have its own ID as well:

```
<input type="text" id="text1">
```

I updated your fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/4Fysw/2/

Answer (score 0):

This can help you.

```
$('#print').click(function(){
    var text1 = $('#no1').find(":selected").text();
    var text2 = $('.para1 input').val();
    $('#output').val(text1);
    $('#output2').val(text2);});
```

Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4Fysw/3/

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I mean. My question was not clear originally, so I clarified it.